# How can I remove white-space when making a responsive website

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am in the process of making this web-design a bit more responsive and would love some advice with where I am going wrong in the CSS of this website in order to stop it having white-space at the bottom and have the footer at an appropriate height after the content.

Currently I am having to scroll through a lot of white-space in order to see the footer.

Here is my CSS

```
    .carousel-item
                {
                    height: auto;
                    width: 100%;
                    text-align: center;
                    margin: auto;
                }
    
                #carouselFade
                {
                    background-color: #f9f7fa;
                    height: 20%;
                    border-top: 1px solid #e3dfe6;
                    margin-bottom:-2%;
                    margin-top: 10%;
                    border-bottom: 1px solid #e3dfe6;
                    padding-top: 2%;
    
                }
    
    footer
    {
        margin-top: 150px;
        flex-shrink: 0;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    html, body
    {
        height: 100%;
    }
    body
    {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    #content
    {
        min-height: 30vh;
        height: auto !important;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto -142px;
        flex: 1 0 auto;
        margin-top: 50px;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px;
    }
```

I have managed to get the videos and images to be responsive and they are moving effectively, however I cannot get rid of the white-space.
Below is the HTML

```
            <style>
                #video
                {
                    display: flex;
                    flex-direction: column;
                    align-items: center;
                    margin-bottom:3%;
                    margin-top: -6%;
                    margin-right:30%;
                    margin-left: 30%;
                    padding-top: 1%;
                    padding-bottom: 2%;
                    padding-left: 2%;
                    padding-right: 2%;
                    line-height: 0;
                    background-color: #faf7fc;
    
                    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
                }
    
                h3
                {
                    font-family: "Brush Script MT", cursive;
                    margin-bottom: 4px;
                    color: #cac0cc;
                }
                .carousel-item
                {
                    height: auto;
                    width: 100%;
                    text-align: center;
                    margin: auto;
                }
    
                #carouselFade
                {
                    background-color: #f9f7fa;
                    height: 20%;
                    border-top: 1px solid #e3dfe6;
                    margin-bottom:-2%;
                    margin-top: 10%;
                    border-bottom: 1px solid #e3dfe6;
                    padding-top: 2%;
    
                }
            </style>
    
        </head>
    
        <body>
            <header>
    
                <!--Navigation-->
                <article class="top">
                <div class="" id="line">
                    <img class="logo" src="logo.png" alt="logo">
                    <h1><span class="lines">D.P.P</span></h1>
                </div>
                <span class="lines">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="inspiration.html" style="color: #cac0cc">Inspiration</a></li>
                        <li><a href="book.html" style="color: #cac0cc"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="author.html" style="color: #cac0cc">Author</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <hr>
                    <hr>
                </span>
                </article>
                <div class="spacer">&nbsp;</div>
    
    
            </header>
            <main id="content">
    
                <div id="video">
                    <h3> A letter to Max </h3>
                    <video controls autoplay width="90%" height="80%" style="box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);">
                        <source src="DianaV.webm" type="video/webm">
                        Your browser does not support the video tag.
                    </video>
                </div>
    
                <div id="carouselFade" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel" dataval="500">
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" style=" width:100%; height: 500px;">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <q>I love you the more in that I believe you had liked me for my own sake and for nothing else</q>
                    <p class="author">- John Keats</p>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <q>But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.</q>
                    <p class="author">- Ernest Hemingway</p>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <q>I have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work.</q>
                    <p class="author">- Thomas A. Edison</p>
                </div>
                </div>
                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleFade" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleFade" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
                </div>
    
            <!-- Preload the images-->
            <script type="text/javascript">
                // preload images
                var image = new Array();
    
                function preload(){
                    for (i=0; i< preload.arguments.lenth; i++){
                        images[i] = new Image();
    
                        image[i] = preload.arguments[i];
                    }
                }
    
                preload("logo.png", "diana mountain.jpg");
    
                </script>
            </main>
        </body>
        <footer>
            <hr>
            <article>
                <p>Connect</p>
                <a href="" class="fa fa-instagram" style="font-size: 30px;" target="_blank"></a>
                <a href="" class="fa fa-twitter" style="font-size: 30px;" target="_blank"></a>
                <a href="mailto:"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" style="font-size: 30px;" target="_blank"></i></a>
              <span style="font-size: 0.5em;"><p>Made by Kieron Spearing</p></span>
            </article>
        </footer>
    </html>
```

I would love some assistance and also any improvements you could suggest to make it better designed and responsive

Comment: can you post the HTML?

Comment: Set  `margin-top: 0` in #carouselFade will do the trick?

Comment: unfortunately not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed your problem with changing some parts of your Html which was an inline style 500px height for carousel-inner class and removing some duplicate styles.

```css
.carousel-item
            {
                height: auto;
                width: 100%;
                text-align: center;
                margin: auto;
            }

            #carouselFade
            {
                background-color: #f9f7fa;
                height: 20%;
                border-top: 1px solid #e3dfe6;
                margin-bottom:-2%;
                margin-top: 10%;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #e3dfe6;
                padding-top: 2%;

            }

footer
{
    margin-top: 150px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

html, body
{
    height: 100%;
}
body
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#content
{
    min-height: 30vh;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -142px;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="menu1.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="table.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Social Media Icon Library -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <title>Diana De Paz Patiño</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="slide.css">
        <!-- TO enable bootstrap -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


        <!-- Responsive assisted with https://dzone.com/articles/using-csshtml-make-responsive -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">

    </head>

    <body>
        <header>

            <!--Navigation-->
            <article class="top">
            <div class="" id="line">
                <img class="logo" src="logo.png" alt="logo">
                <h1><span class="lines">D.P.P</span></h1>
            </div>
            <span class="lines">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="inspiration.html" style="color: #cac0cc">Inspiration</a></li>
                    <li><a href="book.html" style="color: #cac0cc">Nada menos que Max</a></li>
                    <li><a href="author.html" style="color: #cac0cc">Author</a></li>
                </ul>
                <hr>
                <hr>
            </span>
            </article>
            <div class="spacer">&nbsp;</div>


        </header>
        <main id="content">

            <div id="video">
                <h3> A letter to Max </h3>
                <video controls autoplay width="90%" height="80%" style="box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);">
                    <source src="DianaV.webm" type="video/webm">
                    Your browser does not support the video tag.
                </video>
            </div>

            <div id="carouselFade" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel" dataval="500">
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" style=" width:100%;">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <q>I love you the more in that I believe you had liked me for my own sake and for nothing else</q>
                <p class="author">- John Keats</p>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <q>But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.</q>
                <p class="author">- Ernest Hemingway</p>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <q>I have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work.</q>
                <p class="author">- Thomas A. Edison</p>
            </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleFade" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleFade" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
            </div>

        <!-- Preload the images-->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // preload images
            var image = new Array();

            function preload(){
                for (i=0; i< preload.arguments.lenth; i++){
                    images[i] = new Image();

                    image[i] = preload.arguments[i];
                }
            }

            preload("logo.png", "diana mountain.jpg");

            </script>
        </main>
    </body>
    <footer>
        <hr>
        <article>
            <p>Connect</p>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/dianadepz/" class="fa fa-instagram" style="font-size: 30px;" target="_blank"></a>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/Diana__Depp" class="fa fa-twitter" style="font-size: 30px;" target="_blank"></a>
            <a href="mailto:dianadpp@gmail.com"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" style="font-size: 30px;" target="_blank"></i></a>
          <span style="font-size: 0.5em;"><p>Made by Kieron Spearing</p></span>
        </article>
    </footer>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello this has dont the trick for whitespace, but it also has caused it to run off center so got to try sort that out

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring your height in your HTML code to be 500px for that section.  You need to delete it.

`<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" style=" width:100%; height: 500px;">`

make it this `<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" style=" width:100%;">`